# How to solve a catch 22 situation trying to upgrade an old 2009 mac mini to El Capitan with an AppleID created in 2019?

Tags: macos, apple-id, mac-appstore, upgrade

I had the chance to have in my hands an old mac mini from 2009. I turned it on, it works perfectly. Currently it runs *Mac OS X 10.6.8*.

Now, I would like to try to upgrade it to a slightly newer version, like El Capitan.

So, I created a brand new AppleID on https://appleid.apple.com with all my data, including a valid credit card. I checked and Apple did registered and then deleted a transaction with a small amount, to check the credit card. I also confirmed my email using the code Apple sent me during the AppleID registration phase.

After that I opened the "App Store" app on this old Mac, I navigated to the page where I can download El Capitan from, and a pop up asks me to input my AppleID credentials.

I've done it and a pop up tells me that my AppleID have not yet been used in the app store and that I have to verify it.

I click on "verify" and a second pop up tells me I have to update the software and the OS to be able to verify my AppleID.

So I'm now stuck in this [catch 22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22#Concept) situation.

Can someone explain me if there's a way to solve it?

Cheers.

Comment: Can you borrow an iOS device to sign in and verify / validate. Also, is the AppleID using security questions or multi factor/step auth?

Comment: Hi @bmike, I'll try to borrow an iOS device, pretty difficult all my friends are on Android. My new AppleID uses security questions for now.

Comment: Good that you have security questions and have access / know the answers. If you had to prove trusted device - that is where iOS makes it a little easier - especially when you add a credit card to the account and validate it’s you in control. To be clear, I know of no side channel to authorize other than bringing your account to newer OS/hardware, but this is the place in case someone else knows that trick.

Comment: Have you tried running Software Update to make sure you first have all the latest updates for OS X 10.6? For example, there is a [Mac App Store](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1860?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) update for 10.6, so maybe you don't have that installed and that's part of the problem?

Comment: Hi @daGUY, thx for the suggestion. Meanwhile I was able to fix my problem providing my credit card details _for the second time_ in Apple Music for Android.

Answer (score 2):

here's how I fixed that situation.

1. I downloaded Apple Music on my Android phone.
2. I start the procedure to subscribe to the service with my existing AppleID.
3. As it happened in my old Mac Mini, Apple Music on Android opened a popup saying my AppleID had not yet been verified.
4. On Android, however, in contrast with the Mac Mini, the verification link worked.
5. I had to retype the details of my credit card that I had already provided when I created the AppleID for the first time.
6. The verification process completed successfully, Apple debited my credit card for the second time, cancelling the payment after a while.
7. After that, I accessed the Apple Store from the old Mini Mac with the AppleID I had just verified on Android and...
8. It worked flawlessly. I downloaded OS X El Capitan and completed the upgrade successfully.

I write this procedure in case someone else will get stuck in the same, even highly unlikely, situation.